# Restore the default modules in powershell 5.1 windows 10

Tags: powershell, module

I accidentally deleted the modules, how do I get them back?
PSVersion 5.1.19041.1320, Windows 10 x64 20H2

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-module

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}
Script     2.0.0      PSReadline                          {Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadLineOption, Remove-PS...

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

I need:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-module

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Computer, Add-Content, Checkpoint-Computer, Clear-Con...
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}
Script     1.4.7      PackageManagement                   {Find-Package, Find-PackageProvider, Get-Package, Get-Pack...
Script     2.2.5      PowerShellGet                       {Find-Command, Find-DscResource, Find-Module, Find-RoleCap...
Script     2.2.0      PSReadline                          {Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadLineOption, Remove-PS...

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: How did you _"accidentally deleted them"_? If you used `Remove-Module` you can go ahead and restart the PowerShell session and problem should be fixed. If you used `Uninstall-Module` you could probably just install them with `Install-Module`

Comment: If you deleted the system modules in `C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`, your best bet is to find another machine with the same version of PowerShell and copy them from there. The others you can reinstall from the PowerShell Gallery with `Install-Module`, as @Santiago notes.

Comment: @mklement0 I wasn't sure if one could actually delete builtin modules using `Uninstall-Module`, thanks for clarifying

Comment: @Santiago, it looks like you cannot delete them with  `Uninstall-Module`, but the deletion may have happened by direct removal of the folders from the file-system.